# Options for viewing subtitles with itunes movies

Tags: subtitles, appletv

I love renting/buying movies from apple TV, but a lot of them come without subtitles. Is there a way to view subtitles (even if it's on my computer) while watching a movie? Some movies I rent but can't even understand half of what they say. I've found opensubtitles.org but it's full of ads and I'm hesitant to download any malware-infested subtitle player. Getting the subtitles file is fine, but then what?

Also, as of recent, I thought all movies were supposed to include subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

**The only way to do this would be through a third-party application.**

While software recommendations aren't typically appropriate here, a simple search for "apple tv add subtitles" gave a few results, [iSubtitle](http://www.bitfield.se/support/isubtitle.html) being among the first, which seems to suit what you are trying to accomplish.